# How to receive Github WebHook in Google Apps Script web application?

Tags: google-apps-script, github-api

I have Google Apps Script web application:

```
function doPost(request){
  request.postData;
  // operations based on received JSON
}
```

and I have setup webhook in Github.

Why my GAS app is rejecting HTTP requests from GitHub WebHook? Every time I check WebHook log I see error messages:

```
Error 401 "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.".
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve JSON data from WebHook of GitHub using `e.parameters.payload` for `doPost()`. About this parameter, you can see at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

So you can write your function as follows.

```
function doPost(request){
  Logger.log(request.parameters.payload)

}
```

`payload` is a JSON key from GitHub.

WebHook of GitHub doesn't support redirects. So although the WebHook log of GitHub will leave warnings, `doPost()` at GAS can retrieve data from the WebHook.

Comment: Since you don't show your information on GitHub, I don't know your detail condition of it. But, if ``doPost()`` receives data from GitHub, the status code becomes 302 or 30#. 401 of status code may be bad URL. Did you deploy web apps on Google? And you have tested POST to it?